# disable button in a JavaScript processing inside dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to disable the `Details` button in the dataTable

```js
{
  "orderable": false,
  "searchable": false,
  "className": 'text-right',
  "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
    return '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/SubSections/' + full.Id + '">Details</a>' +
      '<a class="btn btn-secondary for-space" href = "/SubSections/' + full.Id + '/Edit/">Edit</a>' +
      '<a class="btn btn-danger for-space" href="/SubSections/' + full.Id + '/Delete/">Delete</a>';
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you searched for generally how to disable buttons in HTML?

Comment: The 'Details' button is an `a` element and cannot be `disabled` using an attribute. If you want that behaviour you would need to either change it to a `button` element, or implement your own click event handler on the element which contains the logic to allow/deny the click event to execute

Comment: @Dan i have tried with jquery and javascript and still trying. i know how to do this in a pure html bu this is different. thank you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that's a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
 "render": function (data, type, full, meta) 
     {
       return '<button disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary" href="/SubSections/' + full.Id + '">Details</button>' +
       '<a class="btn btn-secondary for-space" href = "/SubSections/' + full.Id + '/Edit/">Edit</a>' +
       '<a class="btn btn-danger for-space" href="/SubSections/' + full.Id + '/Delete/">Delete</a>';
     }
```

it's done with button tag  `'<button disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary" href="/SubSections/' + full.Id + '">Details</button>'`

Thanks to @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

Anchor links cannot be disabled. If you want to disable the anchor link, you can try,
to add styling that looks like the link is disabled and remove pointer. Something like this.

```
.isDisbaled
{
  color: #d3d3d3;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

With this mouse click will be handled but in case user uses keyboard, for keyboard event you can use javascript to handle event.

```
link.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (this.parentElement.classList.contains('isDisabled')) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```